# Bluetooth fails to load firmware on boot - Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: bluetooth

I get bluetooth firmware errors on boot in 15.04 on an Inspiron 3647. How can I fix it?

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0c45:8603 Microdia 
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0cf3:0036 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 062a:4102 Creative Labs 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
bluetooth             391136  2 ath3k,btusb
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
[    9.983204] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[    9.983221] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.983227] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.983229] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.983231] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   16.957937] Bluetooth: Error in firmware loading err = -110,len = 448, size = 1906
[   16.957969] Bluetooth: Loading sysconfig file failed
[   16.957937] Bluetooth: Error in firmware loading err = -110,len = 448, size = 1906
```

Comment: Try `sudo modprobe -r ath3k && sleep 20 && sudo modprobe ath3k` then check `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth` to see if the firmware error occurs again.  What kernel are you using `uname -a`

Comment: 3.13.0-46-generic #79-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10 20:06:50 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: still fails after that

Comment: [    9.983204] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
    [    9.983221] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
    [    9.983227] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
    [    9.983229] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
    [    9.983231] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
    [   16.957937] Bluetooth: Error in firmware loading err = -110,len = 448, size = 1906
    [   16.957969] Bluetooth: Loading sysconfig file failed
    [43732.989961] Bluetooth: Can't get state to change to load ram patch err
    [43732.989966] Bluetooth: Loading patch file failed

Comment: please help me update my kernel i got the kernel but i read i needed to select in grub ????

Comment: A reboot after a kernel update should load a newer kernel by default

Comment: It looks like the kernel fix was added to the 3.13 kernels in 3.13.0-47  See [update log](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/3.13.0-47.78) Bluetooth: ath3k compatability issue with xHCI

Answer (score 0):

This is a kernel bug.

You can report it by running in terminal

```
ubuntu-bug linux
```

and follow instructions in your browser.

Comment: that tells me the bug cannot be reported says something bout third party software but thanks for the reply says its not an official ubuntu package lol

Answer (score 0):

From the kernel version you are using you must have Ubuntu 14.04, a kernel update using the following command should help as this issue was fixed back in March with Ubuntu kernel 3.16.0-32

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
```

Reboot and check `uname -a` and if it shows a kernel newer than 3.16.0-32 the bluetooth should work

Comment: : Unable to locate package linux-generic-lts-vivid
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-lts-vivid
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid
E: Unable to locate package libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid

Comment: post `cat lsb-release`  If it is a recent install you may need to `sudo apt-get update` before the other command

Comment: please i need help updating my kernel ???